# Copying a cell down in R

Tags: r, dataframe, na, missing-data

I need to transform this table:

```
1   a   b   0.689723476 0.149916917
    a   b   0.200907662 0.109557062
    a   b   0.684007597 0.703492299
    a   b   0.437375902 0.074223984
    a   b   0.090612241 0.146617232
    a   b   0.526821187 0.895595247
2   a   b   0.507794544 0.731096076
    a   b   0.688987918 0.405801748
    a   b   0.462341505 0.203533346
    a   b   0.750096552 0.889744763
    a   b   0.555074241 0.06610472
```

into this:

```
1   a   b   0.689723476 0.149916917
1   a   b   0.200907662 0.109557062
1   a   b   0.684007597 0.703492299
1   a   b   0.437375902 0.074223984
1   a   b   0.090612241 0.146617232
1   a   b   0.526821187 0.895595247
2   a   b   0.507794544 0.731096076
2   a   b   0.688987918 0.405801748
2   a   b   0.462341505 0.203533346
2   a   b   0.750096552 0.889744763
2   a   b   0.555074241 0.06610472
```

Basically, the I need to repeat the first row downwards until a new number appears, where that number will repeat. I normally do this in Alteryx using a tool called Multi-Row Formula where I do a quick if statement that is like this:

```
if IsNull([Row0:Column1]) then [Row-1:NewColumn] else [Row0:Column1 endif
```

This will create a new column that will the take the value in the above cell if it is null, else it will copy the new value.

Is there anything similar in R or any other solutions to this problem?

**UPDATE**

Including the `dput` data:

```
structure(list(X1 = c(1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X2 = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), X3 = c("b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"), 
    X4 = c(0.057520727, 0.54421869, 0.695381681, 0.866708518, 
    0.764246757, 0.622363342, 0.023082188, 0.140441859, 0.404509135, 
    0.806008319, 0.649705949, 0.607341742, 0.275179259, 0.199698605, 
    0.420250037), X5 = c(0.826617034, 0.338437818, 0.069566611, 
    0.95791903, 0.900005669, 0.533003641, 0.075841125, 0.200099759, 
    0.858293828, 0.271342591, 0.308531235, 0.344739272, 0.259006154, 
    0.824994839, 0.610793113)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", 
"X4", "X5"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(X1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), X2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), X5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: What's the format of your input data? Only cols 2-5 present in a data frame?

Comment: yes, it is a data frame

Comment: Please post a `dput` of your data. The underlying data types may influence the solution method.

Comment: What's in the "empty" elements? Zero-length strings? Spaces? Is that an actual data column or the row names?

Comment: They are NAs. Everything is actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `fill` function from the `tidyr` package. `dt` is your original data frame. `dt2` is the final output.

```
library(tidyr)
dt2 <- fill(dt, X1)
```